# Dynamic method dispatch and variable access in Subclass Reference

Tags: java, polymorphism

Here is my code :

```
class A {

int i = 10;

public void printValue() {

System.out.println("Value-A");

}

}
class B extends A{

 int i = 12;

public void printValue() {

System.out.print("Value-B" + i);

}

}

public class Test{

public static void main(String argv[]){

 A a = new B();

 a.printValue();

System.out.println("===>"+a.i); // This line print 10 instead of 12 

}

}
```

**System.out.println("===>"+a.i)** is giving 10 not 12 ,what am i missing ?
As per my understanding for dynamic method dispatch it should print 12

Comment: You declared it to be of type `A`, so `A`'s version is what you got.

Comment: The point is: field access is not the same as invoking methods. There is no "dynamic" field access. You order "A"s int i; so you get that.

Comment: @Jägermeister : Now I am clear